# Hibernate Named Parameters in SQLQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate named parameters could not be inserted into SQL query:

```
String values="'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'";
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM data WHERE value IN (:values)");
query.setParameter("values", values);
List<Object[]> data = query.list(); // returns data: size = 0 ...
```

However, if I will write:

```
String values="'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'";
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM data WHERE value IN (" + values + ")");
List<Object[]> data = query.list(); // returns data: size = 15 ...
```

Second way returns me data instead of first way.

What I do wrong using named parameters in SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `values` variable should be a list or an array of Strings, not a string, as the parameter is in an 'IN' clause.
So, change your code to the below and it should work:

```
String[] values= {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM data WHERE value IN (:values)");
query.setParameterList("values", values);
List<Object[]> data = query.list();
```

Comment: To be sure, I understand correectly that my concatenated string didn't work only because of IN clause, yep? If it will be something = "my_string" It will work, I quess?

Comment: @user1376885 Yes, it's a Hibernate's behaviour for IN clause. If it was a JPA Query, it should work with setParameter too.

Comment: If your query is something like `select * from some_table where some_column = :value`, then `setParameter("value","my_string")` will work. But, because the IN clause expects a list of values, it does not work when a string is passed.

Answer (score 2):

Your second approach doesn't create a named parameter in the query, it just concatenates a string and you get a permanent query like it was made so:

```
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM data WHERE value IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')");
```

To make the first one work with Hibernate, you have to pass an array or a collection of Objects, not a single string and use a setParameterList method. Just like:

```
 query.setParameterList("reportID", new Object[]{"a","b","c","d"});
```